# How do you convert a 32bit android apk to a 64bit apk without the original code?

Tags: android, apk, 64-bit, 32-bit, converters

Google now requires all apks to support 64bit and we've got an issue due to that. 
We only have the apk that was once developed for us and we use a script that includes apktool to brand it and update the version control number, when we receive an update (which we don't get anymore).

Now in the lib folder, that appears when you profile/debug APK, we see three folders:

1. x86
2. arm64-v8a
3. armeabi-v7a

Our understanding is that arm64-v8a is the 64 bit version, but we still get the notice that we're not 64bit compliant when uploading to the google play console. Including the error that the API level is 27 and not 28, can this also be modified when you only have the apk?

Comment: for 64bit support we must have arm64-v8a and x86_64 in libs folder. you have to check any one of third party library in your build.gradle does not support 64bit.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply! Do you know if/how it is possible to add the x86_64 library to the apk ?

Comment: @Mich Have you found a solution yet?